# Selecting date from Datetime field access

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

It may seems like stupid question  but I cannot  find any  solution for it 
I have column with StartDateTime `dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss`

I need to select only `dd.mm.yyyy` because its access SQL Server `CAST`  doesn't work. Is there any function in MS Access which I can use for selecting only `dd.mm.yyyy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but would the [DateValue](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datevalue-function-HA001228814.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010131676) function work?